# Mongoose search on all fields

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently when I am searching on my database(mongodb) using mongoose, I use find and give the field it needs to find and the `regex` string it needs to match.

To search for all documents containing the string "78934" in phone number I use the query

```
 Contact.find({phone: /78656/i },function(){});
```

What if I want to search for 78656 on all the fields of the table?

I want my user to type any string and get most relevant search results with that search string rather than asking him to also give field he wants that string to match. Does mongoose support such a search query?

Comment: Depending on the specifics of what you're trying to do, MongoDB's [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes-text/) may be a good fit.

Comment: I believe you want the MongoDB Atlas Search `regex` operator: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose supports what mongoDB supports, and mongoDB doesn't support that.  You may be looking into [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) for this functioality.

Comment: MongoDB has Lucene in it now in Atlas. What's the difference for this query: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/regex

Comment: Atlas search commands cannot be used with locally hosted dbs.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this will help anyone who encounters the same issue**
Text Index
MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search queries on string content. text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

To perform text search queries, you must have a text index on your collection. A collection can only have one text search index, but that index can cover multiple fields.

For example you can run the following in a mongo shell to allow text search over the name and description fields:

db.stores.createIndex( { name: "text", description: "text" } )
**and then try running**
db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java coffee shop" } } )